# Is it possible to add Wikimedia Commons images?

Tags: support, images

Is it possible to add [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org) images in the questions/answers without uploading them on imgur? Since the images on Wikimedia Commons are free, it's a waste of hard drive space to upload them on imgur just to be able to show them in a SE question. I've recently asked a question where I provided links to two Wikimedia Commons images but I would prefer to directly include them in the question - without uploading them on imgur.

If not, then I would like to place a feature request to allow this.

Comment: You have to conform their _legal restrictions_.

Comment: This question should be reopened, it is not a duplicate of my question. This question asks whether a feature exists right now, whereas on the opposite my question suggests implementing a (different) feature in the future. This question asks whether linking to Commons images works technically, whereas my question suggests adding copyright information to Commons images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its worth remembering *why* we encourage the use of imgur - if wikimedia changes their links or OP removes the image your image is broken. In future, if SE chooses to move off imgur, it also simplifies the process of fixing links. There's *many* advantages to using imgur, and space is relatively cheap.

You can *totally* link an off site image - just use the hyperlink option, and add a ! in front like so

[image]

<sub>(Example Image taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Philae_Temple_R03.jpg) - Aswan (Egypt): Philae Temple taken by Marc Ryckaert (MJJR))</sub>

That said, chances are, for the reasons I mentioned above, someone will edit it to use imgur anyway, and we really do prefer people use imgur (and maybe link back to the original/attribute as needed - I've used sub tags here)